# Kendo MVC grid column multi filter with nested class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using Kendo MVC wrapper for my grids

here is my column bound code.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.TypeId).Filterable(x => x.Multi(true).UI("").DataSource(ds => ds.Read("Types", "Ticket")).ItemTemplate("getTicketTypeFilter")).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#:getTicketType(value) #").EditorTemplateName("TicketTypes").ClientTemplate("#: Type.Name #");
```

with the help of this handler, I construct the check list for filters

```
function getTicketTypeFilter(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return '<li><label class="k-label"><input type="checkbox" value="#:data.Id#" />#:data.Name || data.all#</label></li>';
}
```

which will render my **TYPE** column with all options

[image: Grid Screenshot]

Now the problem is I am applying default filters to **TYPE** field and others

```
.Filter(f =>
          {
              f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(4);
              f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(6);
              f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(7);
              f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(8);

              f.Add(field => field.TypeId).IsNotEqualTo(7);
              f.Add(field => field.TypeId).IsNotEqualTo(5);

              f.Add(field => field.PriorityId).IsNotEqualTo(5);
          })
```

and when i hover on column filters, thee filters are not checked, but the data in grid is filtered.

How can I make the UI reflect the default filters.

Comment: what do you mean by "three filters", do you mean  f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(7);
              f.Add(field => field.StatusId).IsNotEqualTo(8);, which three filters are not shown as checked? and do other filters shown as checked there?

Comment: None are reflected? Whatever is applied in .Filter that should reflect on the grid